# Check if indexing is exists (Hibernate Search)

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, full-text-search, hibernate-search

Can I check if the index files from the objects exist?
I could start indexing at stratup, but that takes too long.

Another idea would be to check whether the folder already exist.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are after and what your actual problem is, but let me try to answer some of your questions.

> Can I check if the index files from the objects exist?

There is no API for that provided by Search, but provided it is a file based index, you could check whether an index exists at the expected location. However, you would not be able to tell whether it is in sync with the database.

> I could start indexing at stratup, but that takes too long.

If you have existing data you will need to build the initial index. Once you have the index build you can for example rely on automatic index updates (when entities are created/updated/deleted) or you manually rebuild it at given time intervals. Whether you need to rebuild the full index using the manual approach depends on whether you have a way of telling which entities need to be re-indexed (eg via a last update column in the database). Bottom line, you are in control over how up to date the index is in relation to the database. It will all depend on your requirements.

> Another idea would be to check whether the folder already exist.

As explained above, all this check will tell you whether an index exists. Whether this index is up to date or not cannot be (easily) answered this way.

> Is there a better solution?

For what?

Answer (score 0):

You can check index for class and if you don't find any result create index afterwards like:

```
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager());

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder()
            .forEntity(Store.class)
            .get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryBuilder
            .all()
            .createQuery();

    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery
            = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Store.class);

    int results = jpaQuery.getResultSize();
    if (results == 0) {
        try {
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```